# gimp beginner: eraser tool settings

Tags: gimp

I can't get my eraser tool to erase anymore. I must have changed some settings in the options and now it has no effect. 
I'm working with just one layer (white background color), drawing some lines with the ink tool and a wacom tablet.
When I switch to the eraser and try to erase some pixels, nothing happens. My current settings for the eraser are:

[image: Eraser tool options]

Is anything wrong in those options? As I said, I have just one layer. What should I do to get the eraser erasing again?

Comment: I see that "dynamics" should be set to "off".

Comment: Not necessarily, although that could be an issue if the pressure would be close to zero when erasing. The size is rather small, too, but whether that is a contributing factor depends on the overall image size.

Comment: Besides that: this is rather a tech support question than Graphic Design, and should be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher The problem could be that I don't see the eraser in the Input devices configuration. I only see the pen stylus and wacom pad, but not the eraser. Maybe the eraser is not sensible to pressure because of that? If I set dynamics "off", the eraser tool works

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Am I allowed to transfer it myself to another community?

Answer (score 1):

Usual culprits:

- You have a small selection active: *Select>None* to remove.
- Another layer is selected (it can also be a channel): make sure the layer is selected in the Layers list.

Comment: Is not the case. See my comment to my question, it seems to me that pressure sensitivity is not set for the eraser.

Comment: On low-end Wacom tablets (Bamboo et al.) only one tip of the stylus is pressure-sensitive. The "eraser" end is not. Gimp sees two distinct pointing devices (see Windows>Dockable dialog>Device status) and associates two distinct tools to these styluses (by default, paintbrush on the pressure-sensitive one and eraser on the other). So it depends if you are using your eraser by switching the tool on the pressure-sensitive tip or turning around the stylus.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Is that info to find in any wacom's official documentation?